# Symfony2 + Capifony

Tags: symfony, deployment, capistrano, symlink, capifony

I'm trying to configure Capifony to deploy to my remote servers. What I would like to know is if my `uploads` directory should be within .gitignore? When running `cap development depoy` I'm getting a symlink error:

```
executing "ln -nfs /var/www/dev.xyz.co.uk/shared/web/uploads /var/www/dev.xyz.co.uk/releases/20130313103147/web/uploads"

*** [err :: x.xx.xx.xxx] ln:
*** [err :: x.xx.xx.xxx] failed to create symbolic link `/var/www/dev.xyz.co.uk/releases/20130313103147/web/uploads'
*** [err :: x.xx.xx.xxx] : No such file or directory
*** [err :: x.xx.xx.xxx]
```

Is this because `/web/uploads` is within .gitignore so it'll never be pulled from git in order to symlink?

Do I need to clone my repository first on the remote server or does Capifony do this for me?

deploy.rb below:

```
set :stage_dir, 'app/config/deploy' # needed for Symfony2 only
set :stages, %w(production staging development)
require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'

set :application, "xyz.co.uk"
set :user, "root"  # The server's user for deploys

set :scm,         :git
set :repository, "git@github.com:test/#{application}.git"
set :keep_releases,  3
set :use_sudo,       false
set :shared_files,      ["app/config/parameters.yml"]
set :shared_children,   [app_path + "/logs", web_path + "/uploads", "vendor"]
set :use_composer, true
set :update_vendors, true
set :dump_assetic_assets, true
set :deploy_via, :copy

logger.level = Logger::MAX_LEVEL
```

development.rb below:

```
server 'x.xx.xx.xxx', :app, :web, :primary => true
ssh_options[:port] = xxxx
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/xyz.co.uk/"
set :symfony_env_prod, "dev"
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to achieve this.

### Commit the empty folder to git:

Create the file /web/uploads/.gitignore with the following contents:

```
!.gitignore
```

This will allow the directory to be committed to the repository but all content will be ignored. It will create en empty uploads folder on every deployment.

### Create uploads as a shared folder for all deployments

This method has the advantage of preserving your uploads between deployments - probably what you want.

In your deploy.rb create a "firstdeploy" task which only gets executed for the initial deployment, and create the directory at this stage:

```
run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/web/uploads"
```

In your deploy config configure it as a shared path like so

```
set :web_path,   "web"
set :shared_children, [web_path + "/uploads"]
```

I posted my deploy script [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/symfony-cmf-devs/mdTzVowc-LM) if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've created the uploads directory manually at /var/www/dev.xyz.co.uk/shared/web/uploads so I don't think I'll need to create the firstdeploytask. For some reason though it won't create the symlink?!

Comment: I've also updated my initial question to show my deploy.rb and development.rb scripts. On the development server I usually use a specific SSH key to git pull for my other sites on there which aren't using Capifony. This has a different email and password for github than my local machine.

Comment: @gezpage: I'm having the same problem (`failed to create symbolic link /home/ubuntu/myapp/releases/20130323155737/web/uploads`).  I've followed your advice to remove `/web/uploads` from the project-level .gitgnore file, and added the .gitignore file inside of `web/uploads`.  Still the same error.  Could you perhaps share the content of your project .gitgnore file?  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can keep it ignored as for /config/parameters.yml

but you should manually create the upload folder inside the shared folder did you do it?

Comment: Yes /var/www/dev.xyz.co.uk/shared/web/uploads/ exists on the server. - `drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 12 14:21 uploads`

Comment: Is there anything else that needs setting up on the server? Do I need to initialise GIT on the server? I've copied my local SSH keys to the development server.

Comment: If I take web_path + "/uploads" out of deploy.rb then I get an error with /config/parameters.yml  - `failed to create symbolic link `/var/www/dev.xyz.co.uk/releases/20130313113859/app/config/parameters.yml'`